# how do I parse info from a txt file? Python 3.0

Tags: json, python-3.x, parsing

This is just a sample of code

```
{
  "created_at": "Fri Jan 31 05:51:59 +0000 2014",
  "favorited": false,
  "lang": "en",
  "place": {
    "country_code": "US",
    "url": "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/cf44347a08102884.json"
  },
  "retweeted": false,
  "source": "<a href=\"http://tapbots.com/software/tweetbot/mac\" rel=\"nofollow\">Tweetbot for Mac</a>",
  "text": "Active crime scene on I-59/20 near Jeff/Tusc Co line. One dead, one injured; shooting involved. Police search in the area; traffic stopped",
  "truncated": false
}
```

How do I parse this in `python` so that I can get the information in `text` or `lang`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this fragment is incomplete, as it looks like `json` but is currently invalid. Assuming a valid `json` document then you can use the `json` module:

```
>>> import json
>>> s = """{"lang": "en", "favorited": false, "truncated": false, ... }"""
>>> data = json.loads(s)
>>> data['lang']
'en'
>>> data['text']
'Active crime scene on I-59/20 near Jeff/Tusc Co line. One dead, one injured; shooting involved. Police search in the area; traffic stopped'
```

Comment: the txt file and the python coding are separate from each other: 2 different files. I am trying to call (in python) to this text file (called CrimeReport.txt) and then parse it. How would I do that.